# Return destructured object from IIFE in ES6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can't figure out how to essentially do this at the end here

```
export {inMemoryDb, backup };
```

So I want to export the returned value from the IIFE basically as named exports.

**InMemoryDB.ts**

```
const result = (async () => {
  const inMemoryDb = newDb();
  await inMemoryDb.public.migrate();
  const backup = inMemoryDb.backup();

  return { inMemoryDb, backup };
})();

export result; 
// but I actually want to export it as { inMemoryDb, backup }
```

Comment: Exports essentially have to be synchronous. You could export a function that returns those values or you could export promises directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
const result = (() => {
    const inMemoryDb = newDb();
    inMemoryDb.public.migrate()
    const backup = inMemoryDb.backup();

    return { inMemoryDb, backup };
}());  //<-- note here.
```

then

```
export const inMemoryDb = result.inMemoryDb;
export const backup = result.backup
```

Comment: almost, you can't do that because this line complains `export const inMemoryDb = result.inMemoryDb;`.ERROR: `TS2339: Property 'inMemoryDb' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ inMemoryDb: IMemoryDb; backup: IBackup; }>'`. I"ll update the fix in your solution, I had to then() it and remove the async to rid the error

Comment: what's the complain? do not edit my solutions. U should edit your question.

Comment: updated with the error, sorry, I updated your code, if you put it back, that's the error I get above here

Comment: it's because of this line.   await inMemoryDb.public.migrate();  You can just remove the 'await'. but u need to take this into consideration, at the place where you are going to use this variable

Comment: right, cause if I remove it, I'll have an unhandled / non resolved promise that I'll need to resolve it later somewhere after the fact with Promise().all or something I guess...which isn't want I want, I need this to resolve immediately.  So my only choice here would be to resolve it with `then()`.

Comment: guess your problem is currently answered then.

Answer (score 0):

All exports have to be static. That allows many opimisations in the module resolution. Because of that, even if you have an object, you can't export its properties as named exports without explicitly specifying them.

---

However, the main problem of your code is asynchrony. That's what prevents you from just exporting those things as-is, and causes complexities importing it.

Solution options:

1. The [Top-level `await` proposal (Stage 3)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)

   If you use a platform that supports it, transpile your code using a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io), or use [TypeScript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#top-level-await) or later, then you can already use this feature.

   It lets you trash the IIAFE, so you can simply write:

   ```
   export const inMemoryDb = newDb();
   await inMemoryDb.public.migrate();
   export const backup = inMemoryDb.backup();
   ```

   The best thing about this is that you don't even have to `await` it when you `import` it, it's done automatically.

   This is *the* solution to this problem, but for those who don't have access to this feature yet, here are some workarounds:
2. Exporting everything *in* a Promise

   Well, that doesn't answer your question, as it doesn't use named exports. By the way, that's almost what *your* code does!

   ```
    const result = (async () => {
      const inMemoryDb = newDb();
      await inMemoryDb.public.migrate();
      const backup = inMemoryDb.backup();

      return { inMemoryDb, backup };
    })();

    export default result;
   ```

   For this to work, your importer will need to:

   ```
    import result from './inMemoryDB.ts'

    (async () => {
      const { inMemoryDb, backup } = await result
      // Do stuff
    })()
   ```
3. Exporting everything in separate promises

   ```
    const result = (async () => {
      const inMemoryDb = newDb();
      await inMemoryDb.public.migrate();
      const backup = inMemoryDb.backup();

      return { inMemoryDb, backup };
    })();

    export const inMemoryDb = result.then(({inMemoryDb}) => inMemoryDb); 
    export const backup = result.then(({backup}) => backup);
   ```

   Importer code:

   ```
    import { inMemoryDb, backup } from './inMemoryDB.ts'

    (async () => {
      const foo = await inMemoryDb
      const bar = await backup
      // Do stuff
    })()
   ```